# Open another apex page on save button click - apex

Tags: html, hyperlink, apex-code

I am fresher in apex.
   I have one sample form in which i am having three fields and one button.
   I want to open another page on button click.
   Can you please guide me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PageReference Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm)

```
public PageReference save() {
        // Add the account to the database. 
        insert account;
        // Send the user to the detail page for the new account.
        PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(account).view();
        acctPage.setRedirect(true);
        return acctPage;
    }
```